# Remove Pixelation on RMarkdown Plots

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I'm trying to use the following code to create plots on RMarkdown, but for some reason the lines I draw become pixelated (see below). I can't seem to find a solution, as changing the dpi of the code chunk hasn't worked.

link to data: https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/2013-cartographic-boundary-file-state-for-united-states-1-20000000

````
```{r}
library(nycflights13)
library(maps)
library(maptools)
library(rgdal)

usa <- readShapePoly(
"data/census_bureau/cb_2013_us_state_20m/cb_2013_us_state_20m.shp")

conterm <- usa[usa$STATEFP != "02" & usa$STATEFP != "15" & usa$STATEFP != "72",]
conterm_projected <- spTransform(conterm, CRS(conterm_proj4)

proj4string(conterm) <- CRS("+proj=longlat")
conterm_proj4 <- "+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lon_0=97.2w"


sfo <- airports[airports$faa == "SFO",]
jfk <- airports[airports$faa == "JFK",]

latlon <- data.frame(lon=c(sfo$lon, jfk$lon), lat=c(sfo$lat, jfk$lat))
coordinates(latlon) <- c("lon", "lat")
proj4string(latlon) <- CRS("+proj=longlat")
latlon_projected <- spTransform(latlon, CRS(conterm_proj4))


par(mfrow=c(2,1), mar = rep(1,4))
plot(conterm, border="#cccccc", lwd=0.5, main = "Mercator Projection")
points(c(sfo$lon, jfk$lon), c(sfo$lat, jfk$lat), col="red", lwd=2, pch=19)
lines(c(sfo$lon, jfk$lon), c(sfo$lat, jfk$lat), col="red", lwd=2)

plot(conterm_projected, border="#cccccc", lwd=0.5, main = "Albers Projection")
points(latlon_projected@coords, col="red", lwd=2, pch=19)
lines(latlon_projected@coords, col="red", lwd=2)
```
````

This is the output of the code above, notice the pixelated red line

[image: This is the output of the code above, notice the pixelated red line]

Comment: Have you tried using svg instead of png? (with `dev = 'svg'` in the code chunk options)

Comment: @F.Privé Yes I've just tried it now and it didn't work. Though I may be putting it in wrong.     ```{r, dev='svg'}

Comment: do you mind to post a replicable example?

Comment: @OttToomet I've edited it to include the package I've used to get the airports data. The whole set is reproducible from the packages I've added in.

Comment: `fig.retina=2`. That shld be the default in the latest rmarkdown but give it a go in the chunk.

Comment: tried fixing retina, still not working. thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: `conterm_proj4` is undefined

Comment: `conterm` is also undefined

Comment: Very sorry. Must have missed it. @OttToomet, I'm making an edit now to add that in.

Comment: @OttToomet I really appreciate your help, sorry for the constant back and forth because of me. I've made the edits and linked to the data.

Comment: How do you render it?  to html?  pdf?   BTW, a bit of code in the beginning is not recognized as code.

Comment: `conterm_projected` is also undefined.  Please try to check if you can run your code with something like `Rscript code.R`.  But I can see now that on screen, the line is smooth.  Will look a bit more

Comment: I render it to html and have problems. PDF is fine.

Comment: It looks as though antialiasing is turned off.  If you are using the `"png"` device, you can change the setting using this in the chunk header:  ` {r dev.args=list(antialias="something")}`, where `"something"` is listed in `?X11` (at least on some platforms).

Comment: @user2554330 that makes a lot of sense. but i'm not sure what the right "something" is. i've tried "default" and "cleartype"... i'm not sure what to do next

Comment: I imagine it depends on the platform and what else is in the document.  Can you post the results of `sessionInfo()`, and a complete document that illustrates the problem in a minimal example?

Answer (score 0):

Your figure size is too small.  For me, this code gives a smooth line, both in pdf and html:

````
```{r, fig.width=20, fig.height=25}
library(nycflights13)
library(maps)
library(maptools)
library(rgdal)

usa <- readShapePoly("~/d/cb_2013_us_state_20m.shp")
conterm_proj4 <- "+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lon_0=97.2w"
conterm <- usa[usa$STATEFP != "02" & usa$STATEFP != "15" & usa$STATEFP != "72",]
proj4string(conterm) <- CRS("+proj=longlat")

sfo <- airports[airports$faa == "SFO",]
jfk <- airports[airports$faa == "JFK",]

latlon <- data.frame(lon=c(sfo$lon, jfk$lon), lat=c(sfo$lat, jfk$lat))
coordinates(latlon) <- c("lon", "lat")
proj4string(latlon) <- CRS("+proj=longlat")
latlon_projected <- spTransform(latlon, CRS(conterm_proj4))


par(mfrow=c(2,1), mar = rep(1,4))
plot(conterm, border="#cccccc", lwd=0.5, main = "Mercator Projection")
points(c(sfo$lon, jfk$lon), c(sfo$lat, jfk$lat), col="red", lwd=2, pch=19)
lines(c(sfo$lon, jfk$lon), c(sfo$lat, jfk$lat), col="red", lwd=2)

plot(conterm, border="#cccccc", lwd=0.5, main = "Albers Projection")
points(latlon_projected@coords, col="red", lwd=2, pch=19)
lines(latlon_projected@coords, col="red", lwd=2)
```
````

Note that you squeeze two roughly quadratic figures on the image canvas with `par(mfrow=c(2,1))`, so each of the image is approximately 1/4 of the standard size.

Alternatively, insert your two images separately.  In this way both of these should be full size.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I've tried it just now, and still get the pixelation.